# NTLM Authentication in IHTTPClientFactor

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, windows-authentication

I am trying to get a basic app setup using .NetCore.   I created it in Blazor and am using the HTTPClientFactory to play with Dependency Injection.   The issue that I have is that the API I am trying to access requires NTLM authentication.   Since it is not on my domain I need to be able to pass the user name / password and domain.   I can see the WWW-Authentication request coming back via FIddler and the API works just fine in PostMan.   The thing is.. How do I recreate that in C#?

Comment: Use sniffer and compare postman and c#,  The make headers in first request in c# look like postman.  Also verify the TLS version is same in Postman and c#.

Comment: I tried to do that but using Fiddler broke the authentication... I guess it doesn't like that MITM SSL.   I created the headers but was unable to figure out how it was hashing the authentication and doing the retry.

Comment: When referring to SSL it is usually either TLS or SSL.  SSL has been replaced with TLS and the TLS version should be 1.2/1.3.  Fiddler should also show the encryption mode being used for TLS.  I do not believe Fiddler broke the authentication.  More likely you were locked out of the Server after trying too many times with c#,  After failing with Fiddler were you able to connect again without Fiddler?

Comment: I would think that too except when running Fiddler I cannot authenticate.   When I close the app everything works just fine.   I am really just trying to figure out how to pass NTLM authentication via HTTPClient.

Comment: See following : https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Troubleshoot-Fiddler/NoLocalAuth

Comment: Are you running in VS?  Are you an Admin? VS doesn't run with admin privilege.  So you need to create a shortcut to VS and then start VS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Fiddler is using the users credentials.  The issue may be Fiddler credentials and not the c# credentials.

Comment: I will give that a try!    The issue as I am seeing it is that the IHTTTPClientFactory is not sending the followup authorization information when IIS first closes the connection which cannot be right.   I must be implimenting incorrectly.   It just sends the first request which is automatically blocked by IIS and doesn't do a retry.  http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#ntlmHttpAuthentication

Comment: var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

Comment: Authorization Header :   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("NTLM", Convert.ToBase64String(
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
               @"domain\username:password")));

Comment: @Branden that is for basic authentication. I could never get that to work. I have to set Credentials in Http or Socket Client Handler. Which isn't available in factory